# PHP If file_get_contents fails, do this instead

Tags: php

I have a function to translate the current text string using the Free Bing translator API.  I just want to make sure if anything fails or something happens with the Application ID or I go over on requests, I don't want a big error to show.

The code I have right now is:

```
$translate_feed = file_get_contents('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=' . BING_APPID . '&text=' . urlencode($text) . '&from=en&to=' . $to_lan . '');
$translate = simplexml_load_string($translate_feed);

return $translate[0];
```

What I want to happen is if anything fails, so if I add in another character to the URL to make it invalid then I want it to just return `$text` so at least *something* shows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried failing it on purpose to see what happens?

If it's an exception, just catch it and handle it...

```
try{
    //enter code to catch
}catch(Exception $ex){
    //Process the exception
}
```

If there is an error outputted by the function, just @ to hide the error and handle the incorrect output of $translate_feed or $translate manually.

You can try failing it on purpose by simply passing an invalid URI to file_get_contents and then forcefully feed non XML or invalid XML to simplexml_load_string to see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I get two errors along the lines of: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in

Comment: then, you can use @ in front of your functions and check what is the data outputted by the function with var_dump() and finaly use that var_dump to catch the error before continuing...

Comment: This is incorrect, there's no exception, the function returns `false`

Answer (score 16):

```
$translate_feed = file_get_contents('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=' . BING_APPID . '&text=' . urlencode($text) . '&from=en&to=' . $to_lan . '');


if ( $translate_feed === false )
{
   echo "failed";
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do like this

```
if(@file_get_contents("yourFilePath.txt")){
     echo "success";
}
```

Comment: I tried the winning answer.  It didn't work and eventually did this.

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
It's a modified file_get_contents()
get_contents(filename, use_include_path, context, offset, maxlen)
*/
function get_contents($url, $u = false, $c = null, $o = null) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    $status = substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
    if ($status == '200') {
        return file_get_contents($url, $u, $c, $o);
    }
    return false;
}

echo get_contents('https://example.com/');
```

Answer (score 2):

there is [$http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) variable is being created in local scope that we can use it to check headers returned from server. Here is my implementation:

```
public function getData($url)
{
    try {
        $response = @file_get_contents($url);
        if (isset($http_response_header)) {
            if (!in_array('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', $http_response_header) &&
                !in_array('HTTP/1.0 200 OK', $http_response_header)) {
                throw new \Exception('Server did not return success header!');
            }
        }
        return $response;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw new TransportException($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getCode(), $ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`if( !$translate_feed) return "Failed";`

Answer (score -1):

```
$translate_feed = file_get_contents('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=' . BING_APPID . '&text=' . urlencode($text) . '&from=en&to=' . $to_lan . '');
$result=$text;
if ($translate_feed) {
  $translate = simplexml_load_string($translate_feed);
  if (is_array($translate)) $result=$translate[0];
}
return $result;
```